# TypeError: servguild.roles.find is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```java
client.on('message', message => {
  var parts = message.content.split(" ");
  if (message.content.startsWith("sr")) {
    const servguild = message.guild;
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    const role = servguild.roles.find('name', 'Business Owners✔');
    member.addRole(role);
  }
});
```

i have the next error.
TypeError: servguild.roles.find is not a function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I migrate my code to Discord.js v12 from v11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63911361/how-can-i-migrate-my-code-to-discord-js-v12-from-v11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In v12 of Discord.js, Managers have been implemented, doubling as caches and API interfaces.  A [Manager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/BaseManager) (such as a [RoleManager](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager)) has a `cache` property which holds the actual data. This Collection is what the property would've been in v11 instead of the new Manager.

Also, your usage of [`Collection#find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) was deprecated and has officially been removed. Use a predicate/"search" function instead. *See the hyperlinked documentation.*

Therefore, your code would be...

```js
servguild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'Business Owners✔')
```

Alternatively, you would want to use [`RoleManager#fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RoleManager?scrollTo=fetch), if you wanted to make sure your cache is up-to-date. It would be done like this:

```js
(await servguild.roles.fetch()).cache.find(r => r.name === 'Business Owners✔')
```

See [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html) for updating all your code from v11 to v12.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using discord.js v12 you will have to pass a function.
Using the old find is now deprecated (I believe) in v12

```
servguild.roles.find(r => r.name === ‘Business Owners✔”)
```

Otherwise, make sure your guild is defined and available.